# Using a image as a button?

Tags: android, image, button, controls

I've got an image of an "Up Arrow" which I want to use as a button to control the Player's y axis in my Android game. I want to place this button on the left hand side of the screen. Which is the best way of implementing the image button?

Thanks

Comment: How is the game rendered?  Are you using GL? What is the rest of the interface look like? does the button float on top of your games canvass or is it on the side in a area for controls?  ImageButton is probably exactly what you need, but I think the more complicated question you have is the one on layout.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html). Alternatively, you could use an ImageView and use its `setOnClickListener()` method or its XML `android:onClick` attribute if you're using Android 2.1+.

Comment: If you don't want the button-like background, set the `android:background` to a transparent colour; or use the up arrow image as the `android:background`, not the `android:src`.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be going in the right direction. How do I move the button's position? Since it's currently in the top left hand corner. Is there any way to modify the image's alpha channel as well?

Comment: Try the tutorial at (http://goo.gl/VumOI). It seems like this is a really good primer on how to position views in XML. The Android resources at (http://goo.gl/w79j) should help with any remaining questions you may have, as well as explain lots of other view types.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ImageButton class for the image. For positioning, use [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html). Since you want bottom left, it is probably best to use a LinearLayout.

Comment: I'm using LinearLayout already, I've after positioning the button to the far left of the screen but in the centre instead of the top-left like it is now.